# Django: login failed error when trying to connect to Azure database

Tags: python, django, azure

I tried to connect django to Azure database using django-pyodbc-azure and made sure that my settings in setting.py are correct. But still got this problem. I heard that this could be caused by some authentication problem but not sure how to solve this.

> django.db.utils.Error: ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'USERNAME'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect)")

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
    'NAME': 'SERVER_NAME',
    'USER': 'USERNAME',
    'PASSWORD': 'PASSWORD',
    'HOST': 'SERVER_NAME.database.windows.net',
    'PORT': '',
}
```

}

Comment: What format did you use for username? Did you include the server name in the username?

Comment: @DavidMakogon I was using my_login_email@gmail.com@SERVER_NAME. And it tells me that login failed for user my_login_email@gmail.com

Comment: That doesn't look like a valid username (having an email address as a SQL Database username)

Comment: @DavidMakogon just to be sure, the username here should be the one I used to log into azure portal right?

Comment: No. Username is the one you created for your database.

Answer (score 0):

@HansongLi, The connection string of Azure SQL Database is in this format `Server=<ServerName>,<ServerPort>;Database=<DatabaseName>;UiD=<UserName>;Password={your_password_here};Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;`.

Correspondingly, the database configuration is defined as below, see the article [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-ptvs-django-sql/#configure-the-project).

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': '<DatabaseName>',
        'USER': '<UserName>',
        'PASSWORD': '{your_password_here}',
        'HOST': '<ServerName>',
        'PORT': '<ServerPort>',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0',
            'MARS_Connection': 'True',
        }
    }
}
```

Meanwhile, the `<UserName>` should be in the format `<name>@<sql-azure-name>` when the host `<ServerName>` is like this `tcp:<sql-azure-name>.database.windows.net`.

You can find the connection string on Azure portal.

[image]

Or at the tab `DASHBOARD` of Azure classic portal.

[image]